# What were the estimated sizes of the forces in Tarmon Gai'dan?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

During the Last Battle, we see sizable armies from a variety of sources.

What are the estimated sizes of these forces?

A breakdown by individual groups would be ideal.

> For example: Band of the Red Hand, Aiel, Trollocs, Sharans, etc.

Comment: *considers whether to spoiler myself in order to answer this excellent question that's right up my street*

Comment: Would you consider [this](http://www.theoryland.com/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=7771) good enough for an answer, or not canonical enough?

Comment: @randal'thor Hmm, he mentions how he got the numbers, but it'd be better if there was more detail on that process. If somebody like Terez had commented/verified, I'd take it as is.

Comment: the two links at the top of his answer have more details on where those numbers came from.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield Ah, so it does. Referencing them would be good, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't have concrete numbers for all of the parties involved in the Last Battle but in most cases, we can speculate.

[This thread](http://www.theoryland.com/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=7771) from Theoryland includes a breakdown of best-guesses. That information, in turn, comes primarily from [this WoT FAQ entry](http://wotfaq.dragonmount.com/node/136) and [this 13th Depository article](http://13depository.blogspot.com.es/2002/03/military-forces-of-westlands.html), which both gather information from the various novels up through *A Memory of Light*. There's also a quick breakdown of the forces and which part of the battle there were in found in the Wheel of Time Wikia article on [Tarmon Gai'don](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Tarmon_Gai'don).

For all the details of where these numbers came from you should read the articles. Also, note that there are still a lot of unknowns (you'll have to read through the first few posts in the Theoryland thread to find them) on how big certain armies were. But, the best information we have is re-summarized below.

Note that the battle was split into the four fronts: Caemlyn, Tarwin's Gap, Kandor, and Shayol Ghul. I've broken the forces down into who was deployed where, at the start of the Last Battle proper.

### The Good Side

Collectively, the combined forces of Light probably number somewhere on the order of 1.5 million people, including tens of thousands of channelers. Most of the channelers would be in the Seanchan Armies, as would the only viable air force and the dominant navy.

There were ~600 Asha'man still loyal to Rand, scattered across the various fronts. Most of them stayed in Caemlyn, but the bonded pairs of Asha'man and Aes Sedai typically stayed together.

- Shayol Ghul, led by **Rodel Ituralde**

  - Aiel: 420,000 (~2,000 - 3,000 Wise Ones)
  - Arad Doman: 50,000
  - Asha'man: ~30
  - Murandy: ~30,000
  - Tear: 90,000
  - Sea Folk: Several hundred, including all Windfinders
  - Wolves: 100+
  - Super Aes Sedai: 3 (Nynaeve, Aviendha, Alivia)
  - Dragons Reborn: 1
- Tarwin's Gap, let by **Agelmar Jagad**:

  - Borderlands: 200,000
  - Lan's Army: 6,000
  - Saldean Cavalry: 8,000
  - Channelers: ~12 (Aes Sedai and Asha'man)
- Caemlyn, led by **Davram Bashere**:

  - Andor: < 200,000 (~125 channelers)
  - Aiel *sis’wai’aman*: unknown
  - Asha'man: several hundred
  - Band of the Red Hand: Over 30,000.
  - Cairhien: 30,000
  - Legion of the Dragon: 70,000 (mostly raw recruits)
  - Ogier: unknown
  - Perrin's Army: 70,000
  - Other Channelers: several dozen (Wise Ones, The Kin, some Aes Sedai)
- Kandor, led by **Gareth Bryne**

  - Illian: 80,000
  - Salidar: 50,000
  - Tar Valon [Gareth Bryne]: < 50,000
  - Few thousand channelers (mostly novices/accepted; ~220 full Aes Sedai)
  - Seanchan: somewhere upwards of ~300,000 including *tons* of *damane*.
  - Refugees: couple thousand

<sub><sup>*NOTE: The Seanchan army was scattered pretty badly, and Tuon was wary of leaving any of her holdings undefended against locals. It's unclear just how much of her army she managed to gather together and send to Kandor, but the heavy *damane* presence and her air force would have more than compensated.</sup></sub>

### The Bad Side

The bulk of the army of the Dark was, of course, the Shadowspawn. These were originally massed along the border to the Blight, but were gated to Merrilor once the battle started. There is no way to estimate how many Trollocs there are, especially since the Shadow just kept spitting them out, but they are always described in terms of "waves of thousands upon thousands".

- Shayol Ghul, led by **Moridin**

  - Shadowspawn: likely tens of thousands.
  - Black Ajah: > 7
  - Dreadlords: dozens
  - Samma N'Sei (the evil Aiel): unknown, > 20 channelers
  - Slayer: 1
  - Forsaken: 2 (Graendel and Moridin)
  - Embodiment of All Evil: 1
- Tarwin's Gap, led by **M'Hael**:

  - Shadowspawn: ~150,000
  - Deadlords: around 60 arrive by the time Rand does
- Caemlyn, led by **M'Hael**:

  - Shadowspan: ~100,000 ("tens but not hundreds of thousands)
  - Note: these were being gated in
- Kandor, led by **Demandred**

  - Shadowspan: Unknown, but probably ~200,000 (Bryne's ~180,000 was outnumbered)
  - Sharans: unknown, but huge, with "hundreds" of channelers

### The Ugly Side

Padain Fain also ran around killing and resurrecting an unknown number of trollocs, and attacked everyone that moved at Shayol Ghul.

Comment: I culled these together from the 4 articles; I'm going to go through the WOT Companion to see if there's any more details.